# Actionbar icons in main Activity gets invisible when intent from particular fragment Activity

Tags: android

I am stuck with an minor issue in my android app development.

Issue details:

1.I have these icons visible when app launches.

[1st Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRwY9.jpg)

2.After coming to 2nd screen(This particular screen) i am going back to 1st screen by clicking the top left back arrow icon.

[2nd Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuhcB.jpg)

3.When coming back from 2nd screen(This particular screen) to 1st screen icons are invisible.

[1st Screen with issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rr6Sz.jpg)

MainActivity -

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu_new);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    try {
        ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
        Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
        if (menuKeyField != null) {
            menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
            menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    initToolBar();
}

 private void initToolBar() {
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu_white_24dp);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    applyFontForToolbarTitle(MainMenuListingActivity.this);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main_menu, menu);
    if (cartCount > 0) {
        ActionItemBadge.update(MainMenuListingActivity.this, menu.findItem(R.id.cart_badge), ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_cart_24dp), ActionItemBadge.BadgeStyles.YELLOW, cartCount);
        menu.findItem(R.id.cart).setVisible(false);
    } else {
        ActionItemBadge.hide(menu.findItem(R.id.cart_badge));
        menu.findItem(R.id.cart).setVisible(true);
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
} 

`
```

Comment: May be issue in the onStop() or onRestart() methods ! Adding your code will be usefull !

Comment: check for visibility if set to gone...

Comment: @Naveen Avidi i updated my post with detailed code snippet of Activity can you please help me out.

Comment: I didn't understand why you are hiding cart option if cart is greater thank 0 ? Is it correct in your scenario ?

Comment: Yes @Naveen Avidi cart icon with badge and cart icon with out badge is that.

Comment: @Naveen Avidi if you wish i am ready to have a screen share session with you. Will you be able to help me out with that. If fine please ping to my whatsapp app contact - +91-9600320706.

Comment: where you are modifying cartCount variable ?

Comment: In the same activity @Naveen Avidi

Comment: May be you are modifying cartCount to 0 or lower somewhere ! But if menu icon (top left) is also disappearing means, need to see the full code !

Comment: How to get help from you @Naveen Avidi is there any way to reach you out.

Comment: Twitter @Naveen_Avidi